# CMake and OpenCV 2.3 troubles

Tags: opencv, cmake

I am trying to compile/build OPenCV 2.3 with the help of CMake/Mingw.  I got the source from there site, superpack as the call their package. I extracted it and placed it in c:\opencv2.3.

I point Cmake to c:\OPencv2.3\opencv for the source and c:\opencvbuild for the installation folder. Click configure, set a couple of options (I think that I set WITH_QT,and BUILD_EXAMPLES if I remember correctly) click on Advanced, and checked ENABLE_SOLUTION_FOLDERS. 
Click Configure again, then Generate. 
Go to c:\opencvbuild and from there (command prompt). I run mingw32-make, followed by mingw32-make install. No errors.

But, c:\opencvbuild does not show no .lib files, and not .sln files either....What am I doing wrong ?

Thank you very much,
Andres

PS: This is the CMakeCache file, that was generated:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/35186952/CMakeCache.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of copy-pasting, here: http://theroundedengineer.blogspot.com/2011/07/opencv-23-for-vs-2008-from-source.html

Hope that helps.